# No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

I am defining two `EntityManager` beans for two different databases. Each `EntityManager` bean refers to a unique, respective `<persistence-unit/>` defined in `persistence.xml`.

The same code and config worked fine with Spring 2.x.  When I upgrade to Spring 3, I see the following exception while deploying the app in the server:

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2`

Has anybody faced this issue? Am I missing something while upgrading to Spring 3?
I'd really appreciate any replies.

I'm using Spring 3 with Hibernate and JPA.

The problem isn't ambiguity; I'm declaring two `EntityManagerFactory` beans and injecting them as follows:

```
  <bean id="oracleJpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sqlJpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate">
   <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="sqlEntityManagerFactory"></property>
  </bean>
```

This is the full stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.flex.core.io.JpaHibernateConfigProcessor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.flex.core.io.JpaHibernateConfigProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(JpaHibernateConfigProcessor.java:21)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Where is this bean being referenced at?  Are you being ambiguous when asking for a bean of type EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: You should add this information to your question rather than posting it comments.

Comment: The config snippet shows two places that your factories are being used. I'm betting there's a third. Show us the full error message that includes the bean that can't be created because of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Problem is solved. spring-flex-core library was the culprit. The version 1.5.0.M1 that I am using does not allow Multiple EntityManagerFactories. When I used 1.5.0.RELEASE, the error disappeared.The following article was helpful 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100273-JpaHibernateConfigProcessor-complains-when-multiple-EntityManagers-present

Answer (score 7):

Inject your EntityManager like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit1")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

or your EntityManagerFactory like this:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "unit1")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

(You will probably need  [`<context:annotation-config/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) in your context for this to work)

Comment: Sean, We are not using annotations to inject the dependency. We are doing it in the config file and yes we are giving the entityManagerFactory name while passing the reference. So thr should be no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you have a bean of type `org.springframework.flex.core.io.JpaHibernateConfigProcessor`, and it looks like it has an init method that gets autowired with a `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`. Since there are two of them, it fails. It probably is explicitly declared in XML somewhere like:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.flex.core.io.JpaHibernateConfigProcessor"/>
```

Note there is no id attribute, hence the long bean name ending in "#0".

Edit: On second thought, the name of that class looks like some kind of bean processor that runs on ApplicationContext startup, so perhaps it's created by a custom spring namespace element or some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You must do all stuff first like defining
dataSources
eventManagerFactory
transactionManagers
persistenceUnits(must be in separate persistence.xml file) etc
and then compile it will work fine
also dont forget to add annotations in your baseDao class
as @applicationContext(unitName="example")